# PHP isset fail for user login

Tags: php, isset

I'm looking for a way to notify the user that there login credentials failed, like this:

So at the top of index.php (where they login and get redirected to if failed login) I have:

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($fail)) {
  echo "<p>Failed Login</p>";
 } 
 ?>
```

And the check for the credentials is this:

```
  if($ensure_credentials) {
   $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
   $_SESSION['username'] = $un;
   header("location: ../".$un.".php");
  } else {
   header("location: ../index.php");
   echo $fail;
  }
```

At the moment, the redirect is working and they're not getting logged in but the notification isnt getting echoed?

Comment: you are echoing the message after a browser redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be adding a querystring parameter when redirecting to the index.php page after the login failed:

```
if($ensure_credentials) {
   $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
   $_SESSION['username'] = $un;
   header("location: ../".$un.".php");
  } else {
   header("location: ../index.php?fail=1");
  }
```

At the top of index.php add:

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($_GET['fail']) && ($_GET['fail'] == '1'))) {
     echo "<p>Failed Login</p>";
 } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you are giving, it seems like you are never setting `$fail`.